# Mocking syscall errors

Tags: go

Lets say I have the following function I'd like to write a test for:

```
func GetBootTime() (time.Time, error) {
  currentTime := time.Now()
  var info unix.Sysinfo_t
  if err := unix.Sysinfo(&info); err != nil {
    return time.Time{}, fmt.Errorf("error getting system uptime: %s", err)
  }
  return currentTime.Add(-time.Duration(info.Uptime) * time.Second).Truncate(time.Second), nil
}
```

How can I get `unix.Sysinfo` to return an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot.

But you can "abstract it away" in one way or another.

For instance, you can have

```golang
var sysInfo := unix.SysInfo

func GetBootTime() (time.Time, error) {
  currentTime := time.Now()
  var info unix.Sysinfo_t
  if err := sysInfo(&info); err != nil {
    return time.Time{}, fmt.Errorf("error getting system uptime: %s", err)
  }
  return currentTime.Add(-time.Duration(info.Uptime) * time.Second).Truncate(time.Second), nil
}
```

…and then in your testing code have something like

```golang
sysInfo = func (_ *unix.Sysinfo_t) error {
  return syscall.Errno(42)
}
```

before the actual test runs.

Note that this patching must be synchronized with other goroutines which may run testing code which ultimately calls into this function.

---

Note that there exist more hard-core appoaches which abstract away whole subsystems — such as [`github.com/spf13/afero`](https://github.com/spf13/afero) which abstracts away all the filesystem operations available via the `os` and `path/filepath` packages and [`github.com/LopatkinEvgeniy/clock`](https://github.com/LopatkinEvgeniy/clock) which abstracts away most functions from the `time` package.

With such an approach, you write all your code in a way so that it uses a single object implementing a particular interface, to carry out certain class of tasks, and at runtime, this object is either a "real" one or a "fake" one — when you do testing.